# Round Robin with java multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading

I have to create an application in java using threads, but I am new to multithread programing in java. The applicatoin will have many tasks to do, where each task shold be run by a thread. Then I will implement Round Robin algorithm also in java to schedule threads works.

I am not sure if it works properly but this is the code I have done until now (the application with 8 tasks). If it is Ok now I should implement the RR scheduling algorithm, how can I do it? Should it be implemented in a new file or in within main method?

```
public class Application extends Thread {
    public class Task1 extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //task 1
        }
    }

    public class Task2 extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //task2
        }
    }

    public class Task3 extends Thread {
        public void run(){
            //task3
        }
    }

    public class Task4 extends Thread {
        public void run(){
            //task4
        }
    }

    public class Task5 extends Thread {
        public void run(){
            //task5
        }
    }

    public class Task6 extends Thread {
        public void run(){
            //task6
        }
    }

    public class Task7 extends Thread {
        public void run(){
            //task7
        }
    }

    public class Task8 extends Thread {
        public void run(){
            //task8
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application a=new Application();
        Task1 t1=a.new Task1();
        //etc
    }
}
```

Comment: The application does not have any control on scheduling of threads. Thread scheduling is done by operating system. You will need to use semaphores for this purpose. But Round Robin execution of threads negates the purpose of concurrency. Why exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: This applications has only 8 tasks to do, and I want it to be scheduled by another program in java created by me, not to be scheduled by OS. And the Scheduler must be based in Round Robin algorithm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you *have* to implement your own scheduling ? Can you instead use an [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) and let it look after the scheduling of your jobs? From the Javadoc:

> An object that executes submitted Runnable tasks. This interface
>   provides a way of decoupling task submission from the mechanics of how
>   each task will be run, including details of thread use, scheduling,
>   etc.

Comment: It's an answer in that it asks a question about the implicit assumption of having to write your own scheduling, and providing a possible answer to *that* question

Comment: Now you are getting somewhere, but to begin with this was basically a comment asking for more info.

Comment: @Keppil: it doesn't answer what OP asks, it answers what he _needs_.

Comment: @xtofl - I think that's a very good way of putting it. Often you need to take a step back and determine if the approach is correct, *before* dealing with the technicalities of that approach